# ошибка кодировки при pip install

Tags: c++, python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, pip

**'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 3: invalid continuation byte.**
Делаю все по методичке [Создание расширения C++ для Python](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/python/cpp-and-python). Дошел в разделе *Тестирование кода и сравнение результатов* до пункта 3 и выполняю команду:

```
pip install .
```

И он выводит ошибку:

```
Processing c:\users\q\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\pywithcpp\superfastcode
Installing collected packages: superfastcode
  Running setup.py install for superfastcode ... error
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 30: invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 30: invalid continuation byte
```

Я пробовал и setup.py закодировать в utf-8 и module.cpp тоже перевел в utf-8. Не помогло. Что дальше делать? Мой проект выложен тут [github](https://github.com/fryn3/cpp-and-python)

Comment: Видимо не у вас одного ошибка https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4251. Похоже на то, что проблема с кодировкой CMD.

Comment: У меня язык ОС английский, и установилось нормально ваше расширение.